# Importing SQL file with MULTIPLE databases?

Tags: mysql, sql

The mysqldump command is used to import any sql file but only if you are importing ONE database.  The command would be mysqldump database1 > sqldump.sql

But what happens if you exported data from MULTIPLE databases into 1 file?  Is there a command to import one single SQL file and automatically create the databases that are in that file?  Or do I have to split the file into different files for each database?

Comment: Removed sql-server tag, wrong rdbms.

Comment: Did you search for anything? Some suggestions here, for instance: https://askubuntu.com/questions/198170/restoring-multiple-mysql-databases-from-one-file-at-the-command-line